# SQL Server - Ordering by running total for week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This probably is not the best way to do this, but this is what I came up with.  This shows a running total per work week of a product type for each day between M-F.  I would really like to order it so that the ones that have the highest count for the week are at the top.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT   descr, 
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Monday,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 1) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Tuesday,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 2) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Wednesday,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Thursday,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Friday
FROM case1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN product_type WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON case1.product_type_id = product_type.product_type_id
WHERE case1.product_type_id IN(SELECT product_type_id FROM case1 WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4))
GROUP BY case1.product_type_id, descr 
ORDER BY descr
```

Comment: very important question. Which version of tsql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in a subquery and do the order by in the outer query.

```
select T.descr,
       T.Monday,
       T.Tuesday,
       T.Wednesday,
       T.Thursday,
       T.Friday
from (
     -- Your query goes here

     ) as T
order by T.Monday + T.Tuesday + T.Wednesday + T.Thursday + T.Friday desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT   descr, 
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Monday,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 1) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Tuesday,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 2) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Wednesday,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Thursday,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM case1 c WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4) AND case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) Friday
FROM case1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN product_type WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON case1.product_type_id = product_type.product_type_id
WHERE case1.product_type_id IN(SELECT product_type_id FROM case1 WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(Date_Created AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4))
GROUP BY case1.product_type_id, descr 
ORDER BY (select count(1) from case1 c2 where case1.product_type_id = c.product_type_id and c2.product_type_id = c.product_type_id) desc, descr
```